# What's the best way to customise all monotouch.dialog TableViewCells to the same style (Background, etc..)?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Im using Monotouch.Dialog. I'd like to customise the look and feel of the tables. Nothing too major, I can change the background of the tableview easily, the cell borders and use my own custom header and footer views.

What is the **best** way of customising ALL the cells displayed in a TableView?
Is there some point in the Monotouch.Dialog code I can intercept the generation of cells and customise them in one place, so they all, for example have the same background color, font type/color custom detail disclosure icon etc.

Or do I have to individually customise all the different types (BooleanElement, StringElement, FloatElement etc)

Note: Im aware I can use StyledString element, but this only covers the string element type. I want to customise all the cells displayed in my own custom style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way of doing this in the current codebase for MonoTouch.Dialog.

What you could try is the Beta for MonoTouch which comes with iOS5 bindings.  If you are willing to only support iOS5, you can use the Appearance class to customize a few properties (not all, sadly).   You can customize things like the background view across the board:

UIView.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I might just change to regular view controllers, as I've realised I need to change most things to keep with the style of the app.

Comment: You can always alter MonoTouch.Dialog to do whatever you need :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at https://github.com/RobertKozak/MonoMobile.Views which started as a fork from MonoTouch.Dialog but morphed into a similar but now totally different library. It has styling built in.